# REDIS READ MULTIPLE ORDERED LISTS BY UNIQUE HASH - NODEJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, caching, redis

I have an array called personells, that contains a key called mgr_wrkpersonnel_empid. Now as I loop through personells, I need to use the mgr_wrkpersonnel_empid as my unique hash to iteratively retrieve entire lists for each personell and push them to a new array called schedule, and somehow map every list to its respective emp_id as i populate the lists for each emp_id.

Sample code tries doing half of the above, note that i  have already written to redis, but i need to retrieve all data to give consistency to my app. This is neccessary beacuse i need speed in the map.

```
let schedules = [];
personells.forEach((personell) => {
    console.log("personell", personell.dataValues.mgr_wrkpersonnels_empid);
    // Use Redis callback to retrieve the list
    client.lRange(`user:${personell.dataValues.mgr_wrkpersonnels_empid}`, 0, -1, (err, reply) => {
      schedules.push(reply);
      console.log("reply", reply);
      if (err) {
        console.error('Redis Error:', err);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error retrieving keys from Redis' });
      }
    });
  });
```

getting this error

```
GET /scheduler?mgr_wrkpersonnels_designation=2 304 17.748 ms - -
/home/hub/GBHL/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/client/index.js:490
        return Promise.reject(new errors_1.ClientClosedError());
                              ^

ClientClosedError: The client is closed
    at Commander._RedisClient_sendCommand (/home/hub/GBHL/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/client/index.js:490:31)
    at Commander.commandsExecutor (/home/hub/GBHL/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/client/index.js:188:154)
    at BaseClass.<computed> [as lRange] (/home/hub/GBHL/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/commander.js:8:29)
    at /home/hub/GBHL/workforceAPI/workforce-api/routes/scheduler.js:94:12
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at /home/hub/GBHL/workforceAPI/workforce-api/routes/scheduler.js:91:14
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Node.js v18.16.1
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Ive tried getting the files on redis using the cli, and i get all the lists without an issue.

heres a sample of an lrange request

```
127.0.0.1:6379> lrange user:G1257 0 -1
1) "{\"id\":2,\"start\":\"2023-08-05T00:00:00\",\"end\":\"2023-08-12T00:00:00\"}"
2) "{\"id\":4,\"start\":\"2023-08-14T00:00:00\",\"end\":\"2023-08-19T00:00:00\"}"
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

emp ID takes the format GXXXX where x is a number
so i have several users who have records containing ID, start, end values. what i want to do is extract all records for a given user by their empid as the redis hash, taking the form user:empid

Answer (score 0):

I used multi exec, a pipeline workaround in nodejs to enable you execute batch commands with the redis Commander.

Here's my get request now

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {

  const lRangeAsync = promisify(client.lRange).bind(client);

  try {
    const personells = await Personnel.findAll({
      where: {
        mgr_wrkpersonnels_designation: req.query.mgr_wrkpersonnels_designation,
      },
    });

    const multi = client.multi();
    personells.forEach((personell) => {
      const resource = personell.dataValues.mgr_wrkpersonnels_empid;
      multi.lRange(`user:${resource}`, 0, -1);
    });

    // Execute the multi command
    const results = await multi.exec();

    // Process the results and create the final object with lists for each resource
    const allLists = [];
    results.forEach((result, index) => {
      //add empid to the result

      const resource = personells[index].dataValues.mgr_wrkpersonnels_empid;
      result = result.map((item) => {
        item = JSON.parse(item);
        item.resource = resource;
        return JSON.stringify(item);
      });


      allLists.push(result.map(JSON.parse));
    });

    console.log('Lists for each resource:', allLists);
    return res.json(allLists);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error retrieving data' });
  } finally {
    // Always quit the client to close the connection
  
  }
});
```

And these are my results, very smooth. I even have hashes with multiple entries.

```
Lists for each resource: [
  [
    {
      id: 2,
      start: '2023-08-05T00:00:00',
      end: '2023-08-12T00:00:00',
      resource: 'G1257'
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      start: '2023-08-14T00:00:00',
      end: '2023-08-19T00:00:00',
      resource: 'G1257'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      id: 2,
      start: '2023-08-07T00:00:00',
      end: '2023-08-08T00:00:00',
      resource: 'G1189'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      id: 2,
      start: '2023-08-07T00:00:00',
      end: '2023-08-15T00:00:00',
      resource: 'G1258'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      start: '2023-08-04T00:00:00',
      end: '2023-08-10T00:00:00',
      resource: 'G1258'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      start: '2023-08-10T00:00:00',
      end: '2023-08-17T00:00:00',
      resource: 'G1258'
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      start: '2023-08-18T00:00:00',
      end: '2023-08-23T00:00:00',
      resource: 'G1258'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      id: 3,
      start: '2023-08-04T00:00:00',
      end: '2023-08-10T00:00:00',
      resource: 'G1162'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      start: '2023-08-13T00:00:00',
      end: '2023-08-14T00:00:00',
      resource: 'G1162'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      id: 2,
      start: '2023-08-09T00:00:00',
      end: '2023-08-16T00:00:00',
      resource: 'G1110'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      id: 2,
      start: '2023-08-05T00:00:00',
      end: '2023-08-10T00:00:00',
      resource: 'G1262'
    }
  ]
]
GET /scheduler?mgr_wrkpersonnels_designation=1 200 6.069 ms - 959
```

Ignore the non-unique id's. Those are just refrences to another table. SHift ID, that i use to populate and render some information in the front end.